# Unexpected output of top when started by systemctl

Tags: linux, systemd, top

Repost from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70691569/unexpected-output-of-top-when-started-by-systemctl) because it belongs here:

I want to log the cpu and memory usage of a service which starts some time after startup (`webappmgr.service`). For this I have created another simple logging service which depends on it and shall be run after `webappmgr` starts called `perftrace.service`. This shall continuously write the output of `top` and `awk` to the file `/tmp/webapp.top`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Perftrace
After=webappmgr.service

[Service]
User=root
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'top -b -H -p $(pgrep webappmgr) | awk \'{ print strftime("%%H:%%M:%%S", systime())" " $0 }\' > /tmp/webapp.top &'

[Install]
WantedBy=webappmgr.service
```

When the system is started up and `webappmgr` is running, I start `perftrace` by `systemctl start perftrace`. In the file `/tmp/webapp.top` I see what I want to see:

```
04:26:27  2596 testuser  20   0 1887640  24092  17068 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.27 webappmgr
04:26:27  2622 testuser  20   0 1887640  24092  17068 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.06 JSEngine
04:26:27  2628 testuser  20   0 1887640  24092  17068 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.01 webappmgr
04:26:27  2629 testuser  20   0 1887640  24092  17068 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.00 webappmgr
04:26:27  2630 testuser  20   0 1887640  24092  17068 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.00 webappmgr
04:26:27  2631 testuser  20   0 1887640  24092  17068 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.00 webappmgr
04:26:27  2632 testuser  20   0 1887640  24092  17068 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.00 FileDownloa+
```

However, after enabling the `perftrace.service` and rebooting the system, so that it starts at the startup right after `webappmgr`, I see a completely different ouput in the file:

```
04:31:03 %Cpu(s): 33.1 us, 17.7 sy,  0.1 ni, 41.2 id,  1.2 wa,  4.3 hi,  2.5 si,  0.0 st
04:31:03 KiB Mem :  4667484 total,  1369968 free,  2187548 used,  1109968 buff/cache
04:31:03 KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used.  2373988 avail Mem
04:31:03
04:31:06   PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
04:31:06
04:31:06 top - 04:31:06 up 1 min,  1 user,  load average: 40.87, 12.93, 4.54
04:31:06 Threads:   0 total,   0 running,   0 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
04:31:06 %Cpu(s): 11.2 us, 15.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 66.8 id,  0.8 wa,  3.5 hi,  2.1 si,  0.0 st
04:31:06 KiB Mem :  4667484 total,  1362788 free,  2194416 used,  1110280 buff/cache
04:31:06 KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used.  2367116 avail Mem
04:31:06
04:31:09   PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
04:31:09
04:31:09 top - 04:31:09 up 1 min,  1 user,  load average: 40.87, 12.93, 4.54
04:31:09 Threads:   0 total,   0 running,   0 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
04:31:09 %Cpu(s): 11.9 us, 16.2 sy,  0.0 ni, 66.0 id,  0.0 wa,  3.6 hi,  2.2 si,  0.0 st
04:31:09 KiB Mem :  4667484 total,  1358060 free,  2199204 used,  1110220 buff/cache
04:31:09 KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used.  2362388 avail Mem
04:31:09
```

what shall I do to get similar output to when I started my perftrace service manually?

I worked around this issue by modifying the `ExecStart` to start a script which would call `top -b -n 1  ...` (i.e. a one-single batch run of top) in a while-true loop, with a two seconds break between iterations, but it's not delivering any meaningful results either. All CPU load is 0%

Comment: I think the `-p $(pgrep webappmgr)` option is the cause of this problem. On my Fedora system, the `top` command breaks if `pgrep` returns zero PIDs or more than one PID. Your version of `top` can apparently monitor multiple PIDs, based on the output shown. How does it handle the no PIDs scenario?

Comment: @Haxiel I think you are right. The output looks like what top does when it can't find the process. Athough it was supposed to be started after the webappmgr service, there is no webappmgr process yet. I will have to first wait until `pgrep webappmgr` returns a non-zero value before starting the top command.